# How to assign value inside the item template lable in asp.net?

Tags: gridview

Codebehind,

I am getting below error
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {

```
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {

          string  a = Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "item_id")) ;
          string b = Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "order_id"));
            Label lbl = (Label)GridView1.FindControl("Label5");

                int sum = int.Parse(a) + int.Parse(b);
                lbl.Text += sum.ToString();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the location of your `Label5` control, there should be two possibilities:

1. If the label is added to the `Gridview1.Controls` collection, then you should be able to reach it in the following method:

   ```
   void GridView1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       Label lbl = (Label)GridView1.FindControl("Label5");

   }
   ```
2. If the label is added for each row, for example like this:

   ```
   void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
   {
       var label = new Label();
       label.ID = "Label5";
       label.Text = "label";
       var cell = new TableCell();
       cell.Controls.Add(label);
       e.Row.Controls.Add(cell);
   }
   ```

   in order to find the label in your `GridView1_RowDataBound` method, you should use:

   ```
   e.Row.FindControl("Label5");
   ```

Answer (score 1):

`Label lbl = (Label)GridView1.FindControl("Label5");` Write this in OnDataBound Event.

Answer (score 1):

make sure that your grid item label id is same as code behind FindControl id.

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in gv_Name.Rows)                        {
{
 Label name = (Label)row.FindControl("lblitemNameId");
}
```